# How can this be written on a single line?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, list-comprehension

I've seen some Python list comprehensions before, but can this be done in a single line of Python?

```
errs = {}
for f in form:
    if f.errors:
        errs[f.auto_id] = f.errors
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
errs = dict((f.auto_id, f.errors) for f in form if f.errors)
```

Answer (score 9):

Python 3.0 has dict comprehensions as a shorter/more readable form of the anser provided by Steef:

```
errs = {f.auto_id: f.errors for f in form if f.errors}
```

Answer (score 4):

It probably could be, but as per the “Readability counts.” rule ([PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), I'd say it's a bad idea. :)

On the other hand you have “Flat is better than nested.” and “Sparse is better than dense.”, so I guess it's a matter of taste :)

Comment: Coming from a Haskell background, I'd prefer the shorter one. I agree with you that sometimes readability is worth more, but in this particular case, my eyes hurt from seeing four lines for such a simple thing.

Comment: I'd argue that the one-liner dict() version is more readable because it's self-documenting -- it clearly shows it's creating a dict with certain key-value pairs. The four-liner isn't bad, but it takes a bit longer to tell that it's "just creating a dict".

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are quite readable, however you should think of future maintainers of the code. Sometimes explicit is better. List comprehensions rule though :)